# Why does my game pause when 4 balls reach the bottom and not 3?

Tags: python, pygame

1.catch it.py
This is the main program  that can check for events, update the ball and the character ,and finally update the screen

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from character import Character
from ball import Ball
import game_functions as gf
def run_game():
    ai_settings=Settings(1200,700,(230,230,230))
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('catch it')

    boy=Character(screen,ai_settings)
    ball=Ball(screen,ai_settings)
    while True:
        gf.check_events(screen,ai_settings,boy)
        if ai_settings.game_active:
          gf.update_ball(screen,ai_settings,ball,boy)
          boy.update()
    
        gf.update_screen(screen,ai_settings,boy,ball)
run_game()
```

2.settings.py
balls_left=3,this indicates the max no of balls that can be missed

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self,screen_width,screen_height,screen_bg_color):
        self.screen_width=screen_width
        self.screen_height=screen_height
        self.screen_bg_color=screen_bg_color
        self.speed_ball=1
        self.speed_character=2
        self.balls_left=3
        self.game_active=True
```

3.game_functions.py
I believe the problem is in check_bottom(...) function .The game should pause after 3 trials when ai_settings.game_active becomes False.

```
import pygame
import sys
from time import sleep
from random import randint
def check_key_down(event,screen,ai_settings,boy):

  if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
    boy.moving_left=True
  elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
    boy.moving_right=True





def check_key_up(event,screen,ai_settings,ship):
  if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
    ship.moving_left=False
  elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
    ship.moving_right=False


def check_events(screen,ai_settings,boy):

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
        check_key_up(event,screen,ai_settings,boy)
    elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_key_down(event,screen,ai_settings,boy)


def check_ball_character_collision(screen,ai_settings,ball,boy):
  collisions=pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ball, boy)
  return collisions

def ball_caught(ball,ai_settings):

 ball.rect.x=randint(0,ball.ai_settings.screen_width)
 ball.y=randint(0,ball.ai_settings.screen_height-200)

def check_bottom(screen,ball,ai_settings):

 if ball.rect.bottom>=ball.screen_rect.bottom:
     if ai_settings.balls_left>0:
      ai_settings.balls_left-=1
      ball_caught(ball,ai_settings)
      sleep(1)
     else:
       ai_settings.game_active=False

def update_ball(screen,ai_settings,ball,boy):
  ball.update()

   
  if check_ball_character_collision(screen,ai_settings,ball,boy):
    ball_caught(ball,ai_settings)
  check_bottom(screen,ball,ai_settings)


    


def update_screen(screen,ai_settings,boy,ball):
  screen.fill(ai_settings.screen_bg_color)
  ball.blitme()
  boy.blitme()
  pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: you should first decrement the number of balls and then test for >0.

Answer (score 1):

First decrement the number of balls, then test if the number of balls is greater than 0:

```py
def check_bottom(screen,ball,ai_settings):

    if ball.rect.bottom >= ball.screen_rect.bottom:
         if ai_settings.balls_left > 0:
             ai_settings.balls_left -= 1

         if ai_settings.balls_left > 0:          
            ball_caught(ball,ai_settings)
            sleep(1)
        else:
            ai_settings.game_active = False
```